# Byte[] DownloadDataInternal - why error appears depending on the parameter?

Tags: c#, arrays, email, ssrs-2012

I send emails with SSRS reports and if parametr RepFilter>=35 it doesn't works and throw error on this line of code:
byte[] bytes = client.DownloadData("http://localhost/ReportServer1?/MornRep_Sales/Distr&rs:Command=Render&DistrID=" + RepFilter + "&RepDate=" + VarData + "&rs:Format=EXCEL");

Have any idea what the problem?

Here is my full code

```
public void Main()
    {
                string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=ReportsDB;";
                string queryString = "SELECT [email], cast([filter] as varchar(max)) FROM [dbo].[Table1] where [FS1] is not null";

                using (SqlConnection connection =
                      new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        var email = reader.GetString(0).TrimEnd();
                        var RepFilter = reader.GetString(1).TrimEnd();
                        int retries = 0;
                        int maxRetryNumber = 3;
                         while (true)
                           {
                           try
                             {
                                this.sendMail(email, "************@gmail.com","35" )
                        break;
                           }
                           catch (Exception ex)
                      {
                      if (retries < maxRetryNumber)
                       {
                         ErrorLogging(ex);
                         Thread.Sleep(180000);
                         retries++;
                        }
                       else
                     {
                      ErrorLogging(ex);
                      break;
                     }
                   }
                }
           
            }
                    reader.Close();
                    connection.Close();
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    private void sendMail(string sendTo, string bccTo, string RepFilter)
    {
        DateTime VarData = (DateTime)Dts.Variables["RepDate"].Value;
        var fromAddress = "************@gmail.com";
        const string fromPassword = "*****";
        string SMTP = "smtp.office365.com";
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.Subject = "Report " + string.Format(VarData.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        msg.Body ="Good day.";
        msg.From = new MailAddress("************@gmail.ua");
        msg.To.Add(sendTo);
         msg.Bcc.Add(bccTo);
        SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient(SMTP, 587);
        smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential crediantials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
        smtpclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpclient.Credentials = crediantials;
        WebClient client = new WebClientWithTimeout();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "pass", "nn");
        byte[] bytes = client.DownloadData("http://sw-db/ReportServer1?/MornRep_Sales/Distr&rs:Command=Render&DistrID=" + RepFilter + "&RepDate=" + VarData + "&rs:Format=EXCEL");
        string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        string fName = "Distr " + string.Format(VarData.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")) + ".xlsx";
        Attachment Attach = new Attachment(ms, fName);
        msg.Attachments.Add(Attach);
        smtpclient.Send(msg);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps share what error you get.

Comment: Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal server error.
Stack Trace:    в System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   в System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   в System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)
Source: System
TargetSite: Byte[] DownloadDataInternal(System.Uri, System.Net.WebRequest ByRef)
HelpLink: 
InnerException: 
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Comment: Then you will need to debug the remote server. If its localhost perhaps not as difficult.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code, probably an issue in the report you're trying to download. Only something you can diagnose

Comment: Report directly from the site is downloading without problem even if ReportFilter is upper 35